# Setting the class of a particular element permanently from the group of elements created using foreach binding in knockout js

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I just started using knockout js. I am creating group of images using foreach binding of knockout js. Initially all the images have same css class "imageUnvisited" and I am trying to change and set the class(permanently) of the particular image that I click to show the visited state. I am successful in changing the class on click event but as soon as I click on another image, the new added class of the previously clicked image gets remove. I am new it the IT filed so pardon me if you find anything wrong, please help.
Below is the code that I am using:

```js
var vm = {
  item: jsonData.items,
  clickedImageIndex: ko.observable('')
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);

function getVisitedClass(data, index) {
  if (index() == vm.clickedImageIndex()) {
    return "imageVisited"
  }
}

function imageClicked(data, e) {
  var itemTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;
  index = ko.contextFor(itemTarget).$index();
  vm.clickedImageIndex(index);
}
```

```css
.imageUnvisited {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.imageVisited {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: item" id="image_gallery">
  <div id="image_wrapper">
    <image data-bind="attr: { id: 'image' + $index(), src: $data.Src, class: getVisitedClass($data, $index)},click: imageClicked" class="imageUnvisited" role="button"></image>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your current code doesn't work:**

You're storing *one* index in `clickedImageIndex` which is updated on every click. Therefore, the expression `index() == vm.clickedImageIndex()` can only be true for *one* image at a time.

**A "quick fix":**

Instead of storing an index in `clickedImageIndex`, you can store multiple inside an object.

In your `vm`:

```
clickedImageIndex: ko.observable({})
```

In your handler:

```
var clicked = vm.clickedImageIndex();
clicked[index] = true;

vm.clickedImageIndex(clicked);
```

In your `getVisitedClass`:

```
if (vm.clickedImageIndex()[index()]) {
  return "imageVisited"
}
```

**A better fix:**

It's probably a good idea to follow knockouts MVVM architecture a bit stricter... This means:

- Map your images to `ImageViewModel` instances
- Add a `clicked` observable property to `ImageViewModel`
- Add a `ImageViewModel.prototype.onClick` method that sets `this.clicked(true)`
- Use the `data-bind="click: onClick, css: { 'imageVisited': clicked }"` data-bind to update state.